# IAssetFile.Upload returns System.Net.WebException (404) Not Found

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I'm using the boiler plate sample code to create a single asset in Azure Media Services and when trying to upload the asset file I'm getting back a System.Net.WebException 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

This is a brand new  media services account with a brand new storage account (tried to re-create). the storage account has a container for the asset (created by media services API) but no blob.

Fiddler shows the application trying to access the blob and getting back the 404 -

> HTTP/1.1 404 The specified resource does not exist.

The code

```
static public IAsset CreateAssetAndUploadSingleFile(AssetCreationOptions assetCreationOptions, string singleFilePath)
        {
            var assetName = "UploadSingleFile_" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
            var asset = CreateEmptyAsset(assetName, assetCreationOptions);

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(singleFilePath);

            var assetFile = asset.AssetFiles.Create(fileName);

            Console.WriteLine("Created assetFile {0}", assetFile.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Upload {0}", assetFile.Name);

            assetFile.Upload(singleFilePath);
            Console.WriteLine("Done uploading of {0} using Upload()", assetFile.Name);

            return asset;
        }
```

The asset is created ok in media services, the line that fails is assetFile.Upload and the rest operation is a HEAD request on the blob, which does not yet exist -

> HEAD
>   /asset-c3546046-9ffc-46f1-ae19-0071cd93c9f1/video1.mp4?se=2014-05-23T04%3A54%3A48Z&sr=c&si=23fe7a43-27a2-44ff-afc2-53225e950ace&sv=2012-02-12&sig=J%2BapRVKnDmsbKRYrS1dKlw24quVYKH3QB3suMfwiKd4%3D&timeout=90 HTTP/1.1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No brilliant explanation I'm afraid, looks like something got corrupted in the project, cut-and-pasted the code to another project and it all works just fine.

Thanks to JuliaKo for helping on the [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/7c9f07f7-eb9a-4cae-969a-ee830988c3a7/iassetfileupload-returns-systemnetwebexception-404-not-found?forum=MediaServices)

Comment: Uuugh!  I am running into the same issue.  Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

This mediocre answer is a bit late, but I hope it helps someone.  After recently running into this issue, and creating multiple separate solutions with the same code which worked properly, I was determined to find an answer for my original solution which had several projects.

Even more frustrating, creating new projects in that same solution did not help.  As a result, I copied the two project directories (which were responsible for MediaServices) out of that solution to a new location, opened up those copied projects and saved the new solution file.  To my surprise, all worked well.  (wat?!)

I returned to the original solution location, and deleted the .suo file (solution user options) and reopened the original solution.  All worked well.  (uugh!)